# How to create different environments in azure devops and giving different names by parameters or by hand using terraform

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I've been trying to create two different env in azure devops by terraform. But the thing I can't get is to name those env "by hand" in terminal (after terraform apply)

It's working with this code:

main.tf

```
resource "azuredevops_environment" "environment1" {
project_id = azuredevops_project.project.id
name       = var.env_name1
}

resource "azuredevops_environment" "environment2" {
project_id = azuredevops_project.project.id
name       = var.env_name2
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable env_name1 {
  type        = string
  sensitive   = true
}

variable env_name2 {
  type        = string
  sensitive   = true
}
```

After I use terraform apply I have to name those two env in terminal - which was what I wanted.
But I wanted to get this in one module not two (for example by using count or for each) but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

That should be fairly easy to do:

```
variable "environments" {
  type        = list(string)
  sensitive   = true
}
```

Then, say you add the value to the above variable like this:

```
environments = ["env1", "env2"]
```

And finally:

```
resource "azuredevops_environment" "environment" {
  for_each   = toset(var.environments)
  project_id = azuredevops_project.project.id
  name       = each.value
}
```

Here, the built-in `toset` function [1] is used along with the `for_each` meta-argument. This will create two environments with keys `env1` and `env2`, i.e., they will be shown in the output as `azuredevops_environment.environment["env1"]` and `azuredevops_environment.environment["env2"]`.

As per comments (h/t: @MattSchuchard), the variable could be using the `set(string)` type immediately, which would avoid the need to use `toset`:

```
variable "environments" {
  type        = set(string)
  sensitive   = true
}
```

The value of the variable would stay the same, and the resource block would have to be updated to:

```
resource "azuredevops_environment" "environment" {
  for_each   = var.environments
  project_id = azuredevops_project.project.id
  name       = each.value
}
```

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/toset

[2] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each

Comment: You could also define the type as `set(string)` and avoid converting to `set` type later.

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea, I'll update the answer accordingly, thanks.